`Got unexpected undefined` when using Parcel in a Nix shell
I'm trying to set up a very basic nix shell (using flake) to build a Parcel project.
I have a flake.nix file like this:
{
  description = "My Project";

  inputs = {
    nixpkgs.url = "github:nixos/nixpkgs/nixos-24.11";
    flake-utils.url = "github:numtide/flake-utils";
  };

  outputs = { self, nixpkgs, flake-utils }:
    flake-utils.lib.eachSystem [ flake-utils.lib.system.x86_64-linux ] (system:
      let
        pkgs = import nixpkgs { inherit system; };
      in
      {
        devShells.default = pkgs.mkShell {
          buildInputs = with pkgs; [
            nodePackages.parcel
          ];
        };
      }
    );
}

And an src/index.html file:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<div id="root"></div>

However, when I enter the nix shell, and run parcel src/index.html I get the following error:
❯ parcel src/index.html 
Error: Got unexpected undefined
    at nullthrows (/nix/store/qgwakdviwvk2sjv0bqk2w0bjvi4aqx3q-parcel-2.12.0/lib/node_modules/parcel/node_modules/nullthrows/nullthrows.js:7:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/nix/store/qgwakdviwvk2sjv0bqk2w0bjvi4aqx3q-parcel-2.12.0/lib/node_modules/parcel/node_modules/@parcel/node-resolver-core/lib/builtins.js:66:38)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1469:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1548:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1288:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1104:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1311:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:179:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/nix/store/qgwakdviwvk2sjv0bqk2w0bjvi4aqx3q-parcel-2.12.0/lib/node_modules/parcel/node_modules/@parcel/node-resolver-core/lib/Wrapper.js:21:41)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1469:14) {
  framesToPop: 1
}

parcel --help does work, but anything to get some output (parcel serve, parcel build) all give the same error.
My searches so far have not given me any useful insights, so I was wondering, anybody with more Nix or Parcel knowledge have any idea what is going on?

Looks like Parcel on Nix is simply broken, just found someone in the exact same situation as me on the nixpkgs github: https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/350139
